# Turning on/off ALL selected layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, layers

When I select **few** layers in the QGIS 3 `Layers Panel` and press <kbd>Space</kbd> - only one of the selected layers is turned off/on. I want to turn them **all**. How to do that?

[image: few]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In QGIS 3.14+, you can now toggle the visibility of the currently selected layer(s) or group(s) with "Space" button.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

In the Layer pannel, there is an icon in form of an eye : `Manage Map Themes` ([documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#layers-panel)) :

[image: qgis layer panel]

By clicking on it, you can see the option for display / mask the selected layers.

You can also go to the `Settings` menu > `Shortcuts`, find these options (one for display selected, one for mask selected) and affect the shortcut you want.

---

PyQGIS code :

Copy and execute the following code in the Python console and now, you can display / mask selected layers with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut.

The key sequence can be changed with [the `Qt.Key` codes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum).

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QShortcut
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.utils import iface


def display_mask_selected_layers():
    ltr = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
    switch = False

    for i, layer in enumerate(layers):
        node = ltr.findLayer(layer.id())
        if node:
            if i == 0:
                switch = not node.itemVisibilityChecked()

            node.setItemVisibilityChecked(switch)


shortcut = QShortcut(
    QKeySequence(
        # set the key sequence, here Ctrl + Space
        Qt.ControlModifier + Qt.Key_Space
    ),
    iface.mainWindow()
)
shortcut.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
shortcut.activated.connect(display_mask_selected_layers)
```

Make the file `startup.py` with the code above and copy it into ([source](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#the-startup-py-file)) :

- for Linux : `/home/<session_name>/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3`
- for Windows (assuming `C:` is the system drive) : `C:\Users\<session_name>\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\startup.py`
- for MacOS : `Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3`

Comment: Thanks! So I need two shortcut keys to perform this action? Can't assing `on` and `off` actions to one key. Here is feature request for this: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33874

Comment: I've added Python code with a unique shortcut binding.

Comment: I am trying to paste this code as startup marco but it fails because of incorrect `imports`. Some of them I know (i.e. `from qgis.utils import iface`), but cant find the other (`QShortcut`, `Qt`, etc).

Comment: @Mr.Che: added in my answer.

Comment: To run this script when starting QGIS, put it in "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\startup.py"