# What's the keyboard shortcut for select/deselect (on/off) multiple layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, shortcuts

As in ArcGIS, CTRL+CLICK, ALT+CLICK, SHIFT+CLICK works for multiple selection of layers, I didn't find a similar one in QGIS. Is there any?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+H/U will hide/unhide all

Comment: Related (or even duplicate): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347754/turning-on-off-all-selected-layers-in-qgis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the layers and go the menu `View / Hide selected layers`.

You can also set a keyboard shortcut to the `show/hide selected layers` functions: go to the menu `Settings \ Keyboard shortcuts` and search for `show selected layers` and `hide selected layers` and then you can assign the shortcuts of your choice

Answer (score 1):

Select the desired layers in the `table of content` and press the <kbd>space bar</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>mouse click</kbd> on the `group` turn them all on/off.